# Access rs stops if form loses focus

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have Access Form with code attached that runs through a list records to produce reports. However when you run it if another dialog pops up or you work on another app the code stops and the form becomes unresponsive. Can anyone suggest a fix for this please. The code is below:

```
Private Sub run_reports_Click()
    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyFileName1 As String
    Dim MyFileName2 As String
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim strFirstName As String
    Dim strLastName As String
    Dim strWeekNumber As String

    mypath = "\\perfpaup04\common\z Head Office\HO Reporting\Sales\" 'Adjust the path to your location
    strWeekNumber = Forms!frm_Sales_Reports!WeekNo

    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("tbl_BDM_Budgets", dbOpenDynaset) 'Change the table name as required

    Do While Not RS.EOF
        temp = RS("ClientAltNo") 'Change field name as required

        MyFileName1 = RS("FirstName") & " " & RS("Surname") & " - Monthly Data-Week " & strWeekNumber & ".pdf"
        MyFileName2 = RS("FirstName") & " " & RS("Surname") & " - Weekly Data-Week " & strWeekNumber & ".pdf"

        ' set form value to the ClientAltNo Name, so report will be filtered correctly
        Me.List0.Value = RS("ClientAltNo") 'cboName is the combo box name on the form

        ' set the Me.cboName as filter for your report
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_BDM_ReportData_Summary_Graph", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName1, False
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_BDM_Revenue_Summary_Weekly", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName2, False

        RS.MoveNext
    Loop
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    Set DB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by the DoCmd statements executed in the loop. Another approach is to create an Access Report and export it as PDF.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , SomeFilter
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "ReportName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the command `DoEvents` immediately above your `Loop` line.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468 for more information.